# Hide energy bar of Wither Boss

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This is what I'm using to summon a AI-less Wither boss but.. is there any way to hide the energy bar on top of the screen? I was thinking to summon a different mob and change his appearance in some way or maybe summon an invisible entity with a Wither boss on top of it but I don't know how to do this sort of things.. Any help?

```
/summon WitherBoss ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"Custom Name",CustomNameVisible:1,PersistenceRequired:1,NoAI:1,Silent:1}
```

I'm using a Vanilla minecraft

Comment: I would say your best bet is to do an invisible, invincible, noAI, silent pig riding a wither...

Comment: nope, that doesn't work :/

Comment: Sorry, I meant the other way around :D A wither riding a pig. I'm unsure if it would work though

Comment: nope http://i.imgur.com/fjKFhS5.png ... (the pig is invisible)

Comment: Drat... I'm not sure if there is a way then...

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to hide it with just commands.

If you are willing to use a texture pack, you can edit it out in `texture/gui/icons.png`:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You could make your own texture pack, but then you must delete the bar for the Wither's health. However, if you have no knowledge on creating a texture pack, here is a great resource:

Comment: You should summarize the video in your answer.